# Can I share code & resources between Android projects without using a library?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-build

The standard advice for sharing code & resources between Android projects is to use a library.  Personally I find this works poorly if (a) the shared code changes a lot, or (b) your computer isn't fast enough.

I also don't want to get into deploying multiple APK's, which seems to be necessary when I use dependent projects (i.e. Java Build Path, Projects Tab).

On the other hand, sharing a folder of source code by using the Eclipse linked source feature works great (Java Build Path, Source tab, Link Source button), but for these two issues:

1) I can't use the same technique to share resources.  I can create the link to the resources parent folder but then things get wonky and the shared resources don't get compiled (I'm using ADT 21).

2) So then I settle for copying the shared resources into each project, but this doesn't work because either.  The shared code can't import the copy of its resources because it doesn't know the package name of the project that uses it.  The solution I've been using is to access the resources dynamically, but that has become cumbersome as the number of resources grows.

So, I need a solution to either (1) or (2), or I'll have to go back to a library project.  (Or maybe there is another option I haven't thought of?)

Comment: (1) will not help you without (2). All (1) would do is eliminate the copying. I doubt either are solvable with today's build system, other than the "solution" that you are presently using.

Comment: Hummm...  Imagine that shared source & resources are in 'tom.shared'.  Linking source adds 'tom.shared' to consuming project.  I had imagined that linked resources would work the same, but as I type this I start to wonder... maybe that's impossible: all the resources in a project must be in the same package?

Comment: "all the resources in a project must be in the same package?" -- yes, unless you use an Android library project, which you do not seem to want to do.

Comment: yeah, I was hoping that I could have multiple resource packages in a single project the same way that I can have multiple source packages in a project.  If that is not possible then I guess my whole question falls apart.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I don't think what you want is presently possible. The whole Android build system is undergoing an overhaul, and the result (in 2013, I hope) may give you more options here and/or may improve performance of the Android library project to make it more suitable for you.

Comment: Can you please paste one or more of your comments into an answer - I think they are the correct answer - then I can mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your real problem is (2). Fixing (1) would eliminate some copying, but you would still run into problems with (2).

Unfortunately, that really isn't possible. There's a fair bit of fancy footwork that goes on to make multiple packages possible with library projects, and there's no good way to get that same result without library projects. Anything in `res/` of a project is accessed via that project's `R` class, including your copied resources.

> The solution I've been using is to access the resources dynamically

I translated that into you using `getIdentifier()`. That certainly works. Another approach is to having the hosting app supply resource IDs as parameters to the library code -- this is the pattern that the Android SDK itself uses. This is faster at runtime than the reflection-based `getIdentifier()`, and it gives the hosting app somewhat more flexibility, but you do wind up adding a bunch of parameters to your methods and constructors as needed to supply the various project-specific `R` values.